# Missing ethernet on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ethernet

Ubuntu server 20.04.1 (upgraded from 18, which also had the issue) show no ethernet devices on a box I have. It's a random no name ['HT710' PC](http://www.hongsuntek.com/products/HT710C-Intel-Celeron-HT710-Fanless-Barebone-Mini-PC-Intel-Celeron-J1900-2.0Ghz-Turbo-Boost-to-2.4GHz.html) which my googling is failing to find details for, like the mobo/chipset details.
I can't find anything related to enabling ethernet on the bios settings.

I've looked over similar questions but they're all old and are situations where it's at least displayed, whereas this install is behaving as though there's no ethernet adaptor at all.

There are also a large number of virtual ethernet devices - I think due to the docker setup but I'm not totally sure.

I've tried:

- installing the HWE kernel
- installing r8168-dkms

I'm a bit stumped, anything I should be trying to get it to see the network card?

Output of `lspci | grep net` is blank.

Output of `inxi -Nn`:

```
Network:   Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n driver: bcma-pci-bridge
           IF-ID-1: docker0 state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: 02:42:ab:28:06:b5
           IF-ID-2: hassio state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: 02:42:42:09:b1:55
           IF-ID-3: veth0eb533f state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 32:1d:db:16:e2:b3
           IF-ID-4: veth63f7200 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 02:a3:fc:dc:50:bc
           IF-ID-5: veth6857f64 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 92:fe:a6:31:b4:5d
           IF-ID-6: veth6988d61 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 1a:4e:67:09:0f:56
           IF-ID-7: veth6f60c93 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 2e:7c:ea:d7:29:1e
           IF-ID-8: veth9730468 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 06:dc:3e:12:6c:e0
           IF-ID-9: vethcae93b6 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: de:17:e6:fa:67:df
           IF-ID-10: vethe5208c2 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 06:0c:cd:36:f7:2e
           IF-ID-11: vethececa35 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 72:36:ff:38:60:df
           IF-ID-12: wlp2s0b1 state: up mac: 00:8e:f2:c0:b0:12
```

Output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0b1
       version: 01
       serial: 00:8e:f2:c0:b0:12
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=5.4.0-52-generic firmware=610.812 ip=10.0.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:d0600000-d0603fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: vethe5208c2
       serial: 06:0c:cd:36:f7:2e
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full ip=169.254.102.9 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: veth63f7200
       serial: 02:a3:fc:dc:50:bc
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full ip=169.254.71.13 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: vethececa35
       serial: 72:36:ff:38:60:df
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full ip=169.254.136.14 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: veth6857f64
       serial: 92:fe:a6:31:b4:5d
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full ip=169.254.54.189 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:4
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: veth6f60c93
       serial: 2e:7c:ea:d7:29:1e
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full ip=169.254.94.232 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:5
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 6
       logical name: veth0eb533f
       serial: 32:1d:db:16:e2:b3
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full ip=169.254.70.49 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:6
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: hassio
       serial: 02:42:42:09:b1:55
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.30.32.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:7
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 8
       logical name: vethcae93b6
       serial: de:17:e6:fa:67:df
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full ip=169.254.174.39 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:8
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       logical name: veth6988d61
       serial: 1a:4e:67:09:0f:56
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full ip=169.254.165.249 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:9
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: a
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:ab:28:06:b5
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:10
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: b
       logical name: veth9730468
       serial: 06:dc:3e:12:6c:e0
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full ip=169.254.85.132 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

Comment: Can you give us more specific information on the hardware? What is the physical ethernet chipset? Can you include the output of 'lspci | grep net" and 'inxi -Nn' in your question please? Is the ethernet adapter enabled in the BIOS/Firmware?

Comment: Updated question with that info.

Comment: Hmmm... The website you linked says the Ethernet is a rtl8111DL, which should work with stock r8169 driver in the kernel, but it is missing the firmware for the 8111 series. Try installing the r8169-dkms package with "sudo apt install r8169-dkms" and then reboot and test.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I couldn't find r8169 but googling did say that r8168 should do it for the 8111; however no luck after installing that. Outputs of the above are the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, i meant r8168-dkms, that was my typo, sorry. But lspci and lshw do not show any Ethernet adapter... Either it is somehow disabled in BIOS, it is not what it's claimed to be and uses some odd, unsupported chipset, or the Ethernet chipset is defective. You could try booting up a non-debian/ubuntu based OS and see if it matters (OpenSUSE or Manjaro perhaps) but with the kernel not seeing anything on the bus, it seems unlikely this is just a software thing.